# .NET 5 - The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found

Tags: azure-functions, .net-5

When using azure pipelines to build my .NET 5 function I am getting the following error

```
##[error]/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): Error : It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      5.0.4 at [/opt/hostedtoolcache/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

This also displays a `Error : Metadata generation failed` error further down the build script

```
##[error]/home/vsts/.nuget/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/3.0.11/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions.Build.targets(32,5): Error : Metadata generation failed.
```

My build script is

```
trigger:
- master

stages:

- stage: 'Build'
  jobs:
  - job:
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    workspace:
      clean: all
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Use Dot Net Core 5.0.x
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '5.0.x'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        arguments: '--configuration Release'
        command: 'build'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
```

Answer (score 20):

To build .NET 5 functions, the .NET Core 3 SDK is required. So this must be installed alongside the 5.0.x sdk.

In my case it meant that the script needed to be updated to

```
trigger:
- master

stages:

- stage: 'Build'
  jobs:
  - job:
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    workspace:
      clean: all
    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Use Dot Net Core 3.1.x
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '3.1.x'
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: Use Dot Net Core 5.0.x
      inputs:
        packageType: 'sdk'
        version: '5.0.x'
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build
      inputs:
        arguments: '--configuration Release'
        command: 'build'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'
```

Comment: Similar approach works for GitHub Actions

Answer (score 3):

It's a known issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/wiki/Known-issues#net-core-31-dependency

> ##### .NET Core 3.1 dependency
>
> When targeting Azure Functions 3.0, by default, the .NET Core 3.1 SDK is required on the machine building the project.
> In scenarios where the underlying Azure Functions extension does not have a dependency on native libraries or platform specific assets, and this dependency is undesirable, you can change this behavior by defining the following project property: `<_FunctionsExtensionTargetFramework>netstandard2.0</_FunctionsExtensionTargetFramework/>`

There's also a [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/297).

Answer (score 1):

As David Gardiner suggested, a similar approach works on GitHub Actions.

Below and example of Azure function app with .net 5.

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ develop ]

env:
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME: your-functionapp-name  # set this to your application's name
  AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: 'your-package-path'    # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  DOTNET5_VERSION: '5.0.x'              # set this to the dotnet version to use
  DOTNET3_VERSION: '3.1.x'              # set this to the dotnet version to use

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - name: 'Checkout GitHub Action'
      uses: actions/checkout@main

    - name: Setup DotNet ${{ env.DOTNET3_VERSION }} Environment
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET3_VERSION }}
        
    - name: Setup DotNet ${{ env.DOTNET5_VERSION }} Environment
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET5_VERSION }}
        
    - name: 'Resolve Project Dependencies Using Dotnet'
      shell: pwsh
      run: |
        pushd './${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
        dotnet build --configuration Release --output ./output
        popd
    - name: 'Run Azure Functions Action'
      uses: Azure/functions-action@v1
      id: fa
      with:
        app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_NAME }}
        package: '${{ env.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}/output'
        publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_FUNCTIONAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
```